# Extending Vim Mappings to Run N Times

Tags: vim, keymap

I want to be able to type something like 'Ncom' in normal mode that will comment out the current and then next N-1 lines. A key-mapping that I made to do so is, 
`:nmap com ^i#<ESC>j`. This does in fact comment out the current line, but it does not work for N lines in a manner similar to built-in vim commands. What do I need to know about vim that will explain the gap between what I want to happen and what is happening? Also, how might I correctly implement what I want?

Answer (score 4):

```
:nnoremap com :normal! I#<CR>
```

Explanation…

- `I` is the same as `^i` but better. Generally, you should do the following instead of `^i#<Esc>`:

  ```
  I#<Esc>
  ```

  Same for `$a`, by the way.
- `:normal` is an Ex command that allows you to run a normal mode command from the command line. It is used like that, followed by `<CR>`:

  ```
  :normal! I#
  ```
- When a normal mode command is prepended with a `count`: `6w`, the command is executed 6 times. However, the `count` is not propagated to subsequent commands: `6wifoo` doesn't add `foo` before each of the 6 next words. Depending on the command, the rules may vary: consult the documentation if you are not sure.
- When an Ex command is prepended with a `count`: `6:command`, Vim automatically adds a range starting from the current line and ending with the `count-1`th line below. If you do `6:normal! I#`, the command becomes:

  ```
  :.,.+5normal! I#
  ```

  which means "insert a `#` before the first printable character of this line and the 5 lines below".
- When Vim comes across an Ex command in a mapping, with a `:`, it always adds the relevent range. That's why it's best to use `:normal` in mappings that are meant to be used over multiple lines or with a `count`.

See `:help range` and `:help :normal`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this plugin does the job : **https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat**

example:

```
silent! call repeat#set("\<Plug>MyWonderfulMap", v:count)
```